# How do I show current document path at front-end in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm developing my first site using Orchard. I have made few modules, with custom front-end controllers.

Now I need to show some kind of navigation path or route for user at font-end.

for example my current url is `/Companies/Categories/123`

so I need to show path like this

```
Home (/) 
-> Companies (/companies/) 
  -> Categories (/companies/categories)
```

I've tried to google for a while but with no luck.

I think there should be some kind built-in feature to show this path and `provider` which I can use to populate this user path.

Any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about breadcrumbs?

Comment: @martinbc may be :) i've never heard this term before :) just div's class name in `layout.cshtml` `nav`-section:)

Answer (score 0):

Add a menu widget, and check the "Display as breadcrumb" checkbox.

Comment: Orchard already has some built-in `menu`, should I install other widgets (any links?) ? I use orchard with full source code, it has `breadcrumbs` div in `layout.cshtml`, thats why I think it already has such features.

Anyway, not all of my paths exist in menu. So widget can't provide required `path` by itself. How can I intercept it in my controllers?

Comment: You don't have to install anything, this feature is built-in. As I said, go to widgets, add a menu widget, and check "Display as breadcrumb". The paths have to exist in navigation, but you can define more than one menu, and you can add taxonomies to menus.

Comment: I've added new menu widget to breadcrumbs zone. it works. But now I need to add some dynamic elements to it. for example, I have a company category list, and when I show company details page I need its `category` url in breadcrumbs.

Comment: If you're using taxonomies for your company category list, like you should, it should be no problem, as navigation supports taxonomies as a source of menu items.

Comment: no, I don't use taxonomies. I have two item types - `CompanyItem` with `CompanyPart` & `CompanyCategoryItem` (`CompanyCategoryPart`), and I have 1-to-N relation between them.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't use taxonomies for that?

Comment: the first one is that I didn't read about `taxonimies` before :)  (actually I did a little, but decided I don't need them). They do the same, create new content type and vocabulary, as I do. It is not a big deal to create one, so why should I use them? so I created my own vocabulary.

Comment: I've just watched your video about taxonomies, for example in this blog module you need to provide 3 categories: todays posts, last week posts & last month posts (just example). then you need to create custom menu in sidebar, and when you navigate into such category you shuld see `home->blog_name->last_week` in `breadcrumbs`. I thought, that Orchard isn't cool enough to manage such actions using standart taxonomies, so I decided to build my own vocabulary and logic.